# Как правильно сформировать SQL запрос для сложной выборки?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Есть 4 таблицы:

**1) countries(id, name);**

**2) brands(id, name, country_id)**

**3) models(id, name, brand_id)**

**4) products(id, name, model_id)**

В чем сложность запроса:

при выборке з таблицы products нужно фильтровать записи через **whereIn**
по **model_id, brand_id, country_id**

PS: записей в таблице products очень много ( около 1млн ) и запросы типа **JOIN** не предлагать, так как оно существенно влияет на производительность

Comment: как же я живу то с джойнами на базе с 20млн записей в средней таблице? CREATE INDEX не слышали?

Comment: Ничего сложного не вижу в таком запросе. Поддерживаю коммент выше.

Comment: отфильтруйте, в чем проблема то вообще у вас?